# Checking if an element exists in a tree

Tags: haskell

I defined a tree as follows and want to check if a given element is an element of a given tree or not. Here's the code I have, but it doesn't work fully. It only seems to work on the head.

I'm new to Haskell and can't figure out how to fix this.

```
data MyTree a = Leaf a | Node [MyTree a] deriving (Eq)

isElem :: (Eq a) => MyTree a -> MyTree a -> Bool
isElem (Node []) _ = error
isElem (Node (h:t)) (Leaf a) 
    | (Leaf a) `elem` (h:t) = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Here's my second attempt.

```
isElem :: (Eq a) => MyTree a -> MyTree a -> Bool
isElem (Node []) a = False
isElem (Node (h:t)) a
    | (a == h) = True
    | otherwise = (isElem (Node t) a)
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're interested in implementing the function yourself (and bheklir addressed that), but you could also just derive it automatically:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

import qualified Data.Foldable as F

data MyTree a = Leaf a | Node [MyTree a] deriving (Eq, F.Foldable)

isElem = F.elem
```

Answer (score 4):

If we had a binary tree

```
data BinTree a
    = Empty
    | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then we could do a search as

```
isElem :: (Eq a) => a -> BinTree a -> Bool
isElem a Empty = False
isElem a (Branch c left right)
    | a == c    = True
    | otherwise = isElem a left || isElem a right
```

Notice how in the second guard, I recursively call `isElem` on both the left and the right leaves.  If one of them returns `True`, then the overall return value will be `True` because of the logical or (`||`).  This recursion is the key to the algorithm.

I'd like you to think about how to apply recursion to not just 2 branches, but N branches, then combine them using or.  Additionally, I would recommend that you define the function as

```
isElem :: (Eq a) => a -> MyTree a -> Bool
```

And to avoid the use of `error`.  This function should never error.  Either an element is in the tree or it isn't, there isn't a third state it could be in.  Just return `False` instead.

Comment: I modified it as mentioned above, but it still doesn't seem to work fully.

Comment: @user3247171 What is your intended purpose for this algorithm?  Do you want to find if a particular subtree is contained in the tree or if a certain value is contained in the tree?  You aren't using your `Leaf` constructor at all, and your recursion is really only mapping across the first level of nodes, it isn't being applied to each node and their children.

Comment: Want to check if a certain value is contained in the tree.

Comment: @user3247171 Then you'll want to change your type signature to look like what I have above.  You're searching for an `a` in a `MyTree a`, not a `MyTree a` in a `MyTree a`.  Then your cases will be `isElem a (Leaf b) = a == b; isElem a (Node branches) = any (isElem a) branches`

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I explain how to implement `isElem` from scratch by **following the structure** of the datatype `MyTree`.

#### Following the structure

Your `isElem` function should look for an element all over a `MyTree`, so probably the structure of `isElem` should be similar to the structure of `MyTree`.

```
data MyTree a = Leaf a | Node [MyTree a]
```

To make the structure of `MyTree` clearer, let's call `[MyTree a]` a forest, because a forest contains multiple trees.

```
data MyTree a = Leaf a | Node (MyForest a)
type MyForest a = [MyTree a]
```

Now we have two types, and this helps us understand that we need two functions:

```
isTreeElem :: MyTree a -> a -> Bool
isForestElem :: MyForest a -> a -> Bool
```

I changed the second argument from `MyTree a` to `a`, as proposed in bheklilr's answer.

#### Implementing `isTreeElem`

Let's start with `isTreeElem`. We follow the structure of `MyTree` by pattern matching:

```
isTreeElem (Leaf x) y = ...
isTreeElem (Node forest) y = ...
```

In the equation for `Leaf`, there is only one location in the tree where the `y` could be. So we return `True` if `x == y` and `False` if `x /= y`. In other words:

```
isTreeElem (Leaf x) y = x == y
```

In the equation `Node`, we need to keep searching for `y` in the whole forest. So we simply call `isForestElem`.

```
isTreeElem (Node forest) y = isForestElem forest y
```

This is the first place where our decision to introduce `MyForest` and `isForestElem` pays out: We can follow the structure of trees without thinking about forests. In this case, we see that a node contains a forest, so we immediately know that `isTreeElem (Node ...)` should call `isForestElem`. To implement this, we don't have to think about what forests are or how `isForestElem` works, because these decisions are encapsulated in the `isForestElem` function.

#### Implementing `isForestElem`

At some point, we also need to implement `isForestElem`. A forest is just a list, so we follow the structure of `[...]` by pattern matching:

```
isForestElem [] y = ...
isForestElem (tree : forest) y = ...
```

In the case for `[]`, there is no place left to search for `y`, so we return `False`:

```
isForestElem [] y = False
```

In the case for `tree : forest`, the y could either be in the `tree` or in the `forest`, so we call the corresponding functions and combine their result with the or operator `||`:

```
isForestElem (tree : forest) y = isTreeElem tree y || isForestElem forest y
```

The is the second place where our decision to introduce `MyForest` and `isForestElem` pays out: We can follow the structure of forests without thinking about trees. In this case, we see that a forest contains a tree, so we immediately know that `isForestElem (... : ...)` should call `isTreeElem`. To implement this, we don't have to think about what trees are or how `isTreeElem` works, because these decisions are encapsulated in the `isTreeElem` function.

Note that we could have implemented `isForestElem` first and `isTreeElem` second without changing any of the reasoning.

#### The code

Here's what we have so far:

```
data MyTree a = Leaf a | Node (MyForest a)
type MyForest a = [MyTree a]

isTreeElem :: MyTree a -> a -> Bool
isTreeElem (Leaf x) y = x == y
isTreeElem (Node forest) y = isForestElem forest y

isForestElem :: MyForest a -> a -> Bool
isForestElem [] y = False
isForestElem (tree : forest) y = isTreeElem tree y || isForestElem forest y
```

#### Using list functions

If you want to write more functions that operate on `MyTree`, you can follow this recipe of always implementing a forest and tree version of every function. But at some point, you might notice that the forest versions are all very similar and kind-of boring. They feel like boilerplate that doesn't contribute a lot to your programs, but needs to be written anyway. If and when that's the case, you might want to use the list operations from the `Prelude` and `Data.List` modules instead of writing your own forest operations. For example:

```
isForestElem forest x = any (\tree -> isTreeElem tree x) forest
```

Or if we change the argument order of `isTreeElem` and `isForestElem`, we can even write:

```
isTreeElem :: a -> Tree a -> Bool
isTreeElem = ...

isForestElem :: a -> Forest a -> Bool
isForestElem x = any (isTreeElem x)
```

Now `isForestElem` is so simple that we might want to inline it into `isTreeElem`:

```
isTreeElem :: a -> MyTree a -> Bool
isTreeElem y (Leaf x) = x == y
isTreeElem y (Node forest) = any (isTreeElem y) forest
```

At some point, you should start to write code that is more like the last version of `isTreeElem`. But as an intermediate step, while you're learning Haskell (and functional programming?), you might want to focus on code like the firest version above, with separate `isTreeElem` and `isForestElem` functions. If you carefully structure your data types, the simple principle that **the structure of the code should follow the structure of the data** can get you a long way.

PS. By the way, the `deriving Foldable` trick in András Kovács's answer is also following the structure of the datatype, but automates it more.